# How to present a list of custom UserControl for selection in Design View

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, uitypeeditor

Consider the below:

[image]

I am designing a File Explorer type UserControl Library. I have a user control called `Viewer` which are the black controls above (2 or them). It's constructed thus:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Viewer
    Inherits UserControl
```

I also have a userControl called ExplorerManager which manages the different types of associated controls (Viewers, Treeviews and Navigator bars). It needs to hold collections of the different types of control - such as a list of Viewers (think tabbed explorer + split view).

Thus, I constructed ExplorerManager thusly:

```
Public Class ExplorerManager
    Inherits Component

    Private _linkedViewers As Collection(Of Viewer)
    Public Property LinkedViewers() As Collection(Of Viewer)
        Get
            Return _linkedViewers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Collection(Of Viewer))
            _linkedViewers = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I'm trying for as much Designer View compatibility as possible. What I'm wanting to achieve is when you click on "LinkedViewers" in the ExplorerManager1 PropertyGrid, you get presented with a list of the Viewers on the form. At the moment, you just get the standard collections editor allowing you to Add/Remove items (but it is blank on opening and it doesn't persist what you add).

I've scouted about and the closest I could find for guidance was [this codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687430/Selecting-Forms-Controls-at-Design-Time?msg=5777967#xx5777967xx). I could get this working, but sadly, it only works for `Control` not UserControls. I got a cast error saying it couldn't cast Viewer into Control (although this is puzzling as UserControl inherits control??)

Would really appreciate any help. Stuck fast.

Comment: I believe you're looking for a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.6.2). This is used to tell the designer how to implement a UI for your custom control in the properties window.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - I'm familiar with those as have used them extensively with the PropertyGrid control. However, this question has a deeper dimension to it in that it's asking how to effect the Designer view in VS rather than any controls of the build at runtime. Has a quick scout over your link and it doesn't seem to address this. Thanks, though.

Comment: Though not what you were asking, this can save you some coding: [Auto Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: What does it inherit in its `designer.vb` file?

Comment: ExplorerManager inherits Component and Viewer, UserControl in their respective deiginer.vb files. If that's the objects you were querying